# How this Javascript looks in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code. I have a table with some values. This line works fine, but i want to make it with jquery. Any ideas?

```
$(".classX #nameY")
.val(document.getElementById("objektId")
.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]
.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Comment: `$(".classX #nameY").val(` Is jQuery

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: Which line works fine??

Comment: He wants to replace the bit inside `val()` with jQuery.  What's so hard to understand about that???  @Scriptor can you show us the markup so we know what you're getting the value from?

Comment: Sorry, i did not express myself properly. I mean this val(document.getElementById("objektId").getElementsByTagName('td')[0].firstChild.nodeValue);

Comment: `$(".classX #nameY").val($("#objektId").find('td[0]:first-child').val());`

Comment: Show your `HTML` of table.

Comment: `$(".classX #nameY").val($('#objektId td:eq(0)').contents().first().text());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery code will looks like,

```
$("#nameY").val($("#objektId").find('td:eq(0)').children().eq(0).html());
```

Comment: My mistake, I think it should be html() or text()

Comment: @Archer thanks for the suggestions. edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".classX #nameY").val($("#objektId").find('td').first().children().first().val());
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.